# Error Compilación "undefined reference to Win Main"

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Estoy implementando en Dev C++ una pila de máximos utilizando el contenedor "vector". He estado arreglando todos los errores de código pero sin embargo, a la hora de compilar obtengo un mensaje así:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o)   In function `main':
>
> 18        C:\crossdev\src\mingw-w64-v3-git\mingw-w64-crt\crt\crt0_c.c undefined reference to `WinMain'
>
> C:\Users\Guillermo\Desktop\PRACTICA 3 - ED\collect2.exe   [Error] ld returned 1 exit status

Tengo un tercer archivo con su función "main" para poder probar dicha clase.
Aquí os dejo el código tanto del archivo .h como .cpp.

**Archivo de cabecera "Pila_max_VD.h"**

```
#ifndef __PilaMax_VD__
#define __PilaMax_VD__

#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct elemento{
    int dato;
    int max;
    
};

class PilaMax{
    private:
        vector<elemento> elementos;
    public: 
        PilaMax();
        PilaMax(const PilaMax & origen);
        ~PilaMax();
        PilaMax& operator= (const PilaMax & origen);
        bool vacia();
        void poner(const int &n);
        void quitar();
        elemento& tope();
        int maximo();
        int num_elementos();    
};

#endif
```

**Archivo cpp "Pila_max_VD.cpp"**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include "Pila_max_VD.h"

using namespace std;

PilaMax::PilaMax(const PilaMax & origen){   
    *this=origen;
}

PilaMax::~PilaMax(){
    elementos.erase(elementos.begin(),elementos.end()-1);
}

PilaMax& PilaMax::operator= (const PilaMax & origen){
    for(int i=0;i<origen.elementos.size();i++){
        elementos.push_back(origen.elementos[i]);
        
    }
    
    return *this;
}

bool PilaMax::vacia(){
    return elementos.empty();
}

void PilaMax::poner(const int &n){
    // Hallamos el nuevo máximo
    int mayor;
    
    if(n>maximo()){
        mayor = n;
    }
    else{
        mayor = maximo();
    }
    
    elemento nuevo;
    nuevo.dato = n;
    nuevo.max = mayor;
    
    elementos.push_back(nuevo);
}

void PilaMax::quitar(){
    assert(!elementos.empty());
    elementos.pop_back();
}

elemento& PilaMax::tope(){
    assert(!elementos.empty());
    return elementos[elementos.size()-1];
}

int PilaMax::maximo(){
    assert(!elementos.empty());
    return tope().max;
}
    
int PilaMax::num_elementos(){
    return elementos.size();
}
```

Comment: Dev-C++ esta lleno de bugs, prueba tu codigo con otro compilador. Que tal si buscas gdb online, si no te da errores ahi, tu codigo esta correcto, es solo Dev-C++. Posdata: El destructor esta de mas, ya que el vector ya se encarga de eliminar los elementos. De hecho, si no hay cosas que tengas que manejar manualmente (como un puntero al que le asignaste memoria con new) no tienes que definir el que es por copia, ni el operador=. Busca las reglas de 0, 3 y 5

Comment: He probado con gdb online pero sigo teniendo el mismo error de compilación... si coloco toda la clase dentro de un mismo archivo en lugar de utilizar un .h y un .cpp me funciona perfectamente. así que tiene que ser algún error a la hora de dividir la clase en un archivo de cabecera  y un .cpp, pero no logro encontrarlo

Comment: Referencia a valor variable anterior al resultado de una funcion para esa variable

Comment: En el codigo que compartes no defines `main` en ningun lado. Lo defines en otro archivo? De ser el caso, estas seguro de que se esta incluyendo?